# Clear stack being navigated to React-Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My react-native application consists of a DrawerNavigator that contains several StackNavigators. A simplified example of my structure looks like this

```
- Drawer
  - Stack 1
    - Screen 1
    - Screen 2
  - Stack 2
    - Screen 1
    - Screen 2
```

My problem is the following: 
I am on Screen 1 of Stack 1. I navigate to screen 1 of Stack 2 using the Drawer. From Screen 1 of Stack 2 I navigate to Screen 2 of Stack 2 on the press of a button. I then navigate back to Stack 1 using the Drawer. I again return to Stack 2 using the Drawer. I am now on Screen 1 of Stack 2, but there is a back button in the header, and it appears that my current screen has just been placed on top of the old stack. Pressing it navigates me to Screen 2 of Stack 2, and pressing it again navigates me to Screen 1 of Stack 2.

When navigating back to a stack in the drawer I would expect it to return me to the first item in the stack with a fresh stack - that is, with no back button.

Is this behavior expected? If so, is there anything I can do to 'clear' the stack when I navigate to it from the drawer?

Here is an Expo example with bare minimum code to reproduce my structure and the issue: https://snack.expo.io/rk2HV-HNf

Comment: No, It can't be like that. Please show more your code.

Comment: @BrightLee I added code in an Expo example

Comment: I looked your code, and there is a typo in Screen3. It says it's screen 4.

Comment: I don't see that error. I see that Drawer Item 2 Screen 1 is incorrectly labeled Screen 2 in the text, but neither of those are related to the issue I mentioned in the post above

Comment: Ah.... now I get it. What the heck is this? I never know this is happening.

Comment: Do you think this is relative issue with https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/389 or https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/199 ? I will share if I find a solution.

Comment: I think we should keep in eyes on this issue. https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1449

Comment: By the way, the dumb solution will be that you can add 'headerLeft' button on each first screen of Stack. Like a 'hamburger' button. If you add this button, the weird back button will not show. Although there will be a memory leak.

Comment: Ah, I remembered now how I figured out. You can lock your 'drawer' when your stack goes deep. Then, you can't open drawer unless if you are in the root of Stack. This approach will prevent this weird behavior. That's how I did.

Answer (score 0):

In react-navigation, if you want to go back, instead of creating a new screen, you need to use `this.props.navigation.goBack()`. If you use `navigate` method, it creates a new screen, hence back button.

However, there is also another way. In your case you do not need this, however you can also define a stack from scratch using `NavigationActions` and dispatch it to reset navigation stack.